# Node express can read cookies in DELETE request, but not in POST request

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, axios, httponly

I have a request `DELETE /refresh` in my node express application. It is able to read HTTP-only cookies. If I re-write it to a `POST` request then the application can no longer read the value of the token, and sees it as *undefined*.

I notice this behavior when I call the server using React/axios. If I make the calls from visual studio / REST Client then both `POST` and `DELETE` work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, axios.delete and axios.post don't take the same arguments.

`{withCredentials: true }` was being passed as body instead of being used as intended.